# Networkx. Graph visualization.Python.Circular layout

Tags: python, layout, graph, networkx

I got some problems with visualizing a graph using circular layout.
I'm using Python and `Networkx 2.5v`.
But here is what I got. It looks so messy. How can I do it?

My code:

```
pos_fb = nx.circular_layout(fb)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
nx.draw_networkx(fb, pos_fb, center='array_like', **options)
```

My result:

[image: Circular layout network]

Comment: You need to provide more context. Do you think that you've provided sufficient information for someone to adequately help you? Also, instead of sharing your code as an image, paste it in your question body instead, and use the editor's code formatting tool.

Comment: How large is your graph? If it contains thousands of nodes and edges, the result should look exactly like yours.

Answer (score 0):

To improve your drawing you can:

#### 1. Use `node_size` parameter to make your nodes smaller, e.g.:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=0.05)
```

#### 2. Use the `width` and `alpha` parameters to highlight the most connected nodes, e.g:

```
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, center="array_like", width=0.01, alpha=0.5)
```

#### Example

Here is a drawing of a scale-free network with 10,000 nodes using the Barabasi-Albert model and a circular layout:

```
G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(10000, 2, seed=1)
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=0.05)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, center="array_like", width=0.01, alpha=0.5)
```

#### Result

[image: Example]

Please note that these values are for networks with a relatively large amount of nodes.

Comment: Tell me if you need further help